# problem with images on a custom 404 page, django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to make custom 404 page by adding an image to the page. Problem is that image is not displaying on a page. This image is accessible from any other page in each app in DEBUG TRUE or FALSE mode, no difference, except 404 page where it represented as a just an empty frame.

Image is placed in app/static/app root. Tried to place it is main static root  -no difference.

```py
# urls.py

handler403 = curry(permission_denied, exception=Exception('Permission Denied'),
                   template_name='errors/403.html')
handler404 = curry(page_not_found, exception=Exception('Page not Found'),
                   template_name='errors/404.html')
```

handler 403 and handler 404 works fine, except images failure.

```html
# template
<!-- templates/errors/404.html  -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} error 404   {%  endblock %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

    <img  src="{% static "appname/404.png" %}" alt="404">


{% endblock content %}
```

Problem is only on 404/403 pages. Everywhere else -no problems at all. Text itself displays normally.

Question is what should I check in terms of possible pitfalls I possible keeping out of scope ?

thanks in advance

p.s.   tried

```py
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}404.png" >
```

still no effect

Comment: What happens if you render the page with a network console? Do you see a request to fetch the image?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem . yes - 67 4.978539 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 HTTP 912 GET /static/boats/404.png HTTP/1.1. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem ...hm..maybe it is some cache issues???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to run server in the following mode:

manage.py runserver --insecure

Comment: Not sure if this is a viable solution. Do you have any more info regarding this?